# C# code worked until added final step in loop, now new is overriding old code.

Tags: c#, loops

I am in visual studio making a random lottery program. it SHOULD work like this:  User enters 3 numbers, then hits the button. The program then generates 3 random numbers (up to) 1000 times and displays the random generated numbers in a listbox. If the users numbers are generated in order, it will STOP at whatever number attempt it is on and say "success! after "x" tries"

If the random numbers do not match the users numbers after 1000, a message will pop up saying "no match found after 1000 tries"

The program worked until I got to the last step. I added this code:

```
    //  -keep track of the matching status of each digit in a boolean

            bool theyMatch = (random1 == userEntered1stDigit) && (random2 == userEntered2ndDigit) && (random3 == userEntered3rdDigit);

            //check all three boolean match variables, if they are all true then we have a match to the winning number, exit out of the while
            if (theyMatch)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success! Match found for all 3 digits. It took " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //add what happened to the event log
                MessageBox.Show("No match found after " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
                return;
            }
```

Now when I run it, it stops at attempt #1 and gives the success or failure message. What am I missing that the new code is overriding the old code??

Here is the whole thing:

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //DECLARE CLASS LEVEL FIELD VARIABLES
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick3 = 500;
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick4 = 5000;
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick5 = 50000;

    private void myBtnGenRandomNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
        int userEntered1stDigit = 0;
        int userEntered2ndDigit = 0;
        int userEntered3rdDigit = 0;


        //INPUT-VALIDATION
        //winning number: validate the 1st digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox1stDigit.Text, out userEntered1stDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the first box");
            return;
        }
        //winning number: validate the 2nd digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox2ndDigit.Text, out userEntered2ndDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the second box");
            return;
        }
        //winning number: validate the 3rd digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox3rdDigit.Text, out userEntered3rdDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the third box");
            return;
        }


        //INITIALIZE ANY VARIABLES
        userEntered1stDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox1stDigit.Text);
        userEntered2ndDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox2ndDigit.Text);
        userEntered3rdDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox3rdDigit.Text);

        //GOOD SO FAR

        //PROCESSING
        //setup your own Random number generator object
        int random1 = 0;
        int random2 = 0;
        int random3 = 0;

        Random myRandomNumberObject = new Random();
        int matchNum1;
        int matchNum2;
        int matchNum3;

        //clear the list box
        myListBoxResults.Items.Clear();

        //set number of attempts = 0
        int myAttemptsInt;
        myAttemptsInt = 0;


        //LOOP THROUGH AND CREATE SETS OF 3 RANDOM DIGITS EACH TIME THROUGH LOOP UNTIL A MATCH IS FOUND OR TRY 1,000 TIMES
        while (myAttemptsInt <= 1000) 
        {

            if (myAttemptsInt <= 999)
            {
                //ok
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 1
            random1 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);
            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 2
            random2 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);
            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 3
            random3 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);


            //display the number of match attempts so far

            //attempt # originally went here
            myAttemptsInt = myAttemptsInt + 1;

            int index = myListBoxResults.Items.Add("Attempt # " + myAttemptsInt);

            //display the generated digit 1,2,3 in the labels on the Form
            matchNum1 = random1;
            myLabelGenerated1stDigit.Text = matchNum1.ToString();
            matchNum2 = random2;
            myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.Text = matchNum2.ToString();
            matchNum3 = random3;
            myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.Text = matchNum3.ToString();

            //set the Label BackColor of all the generated digits to Color.LightGray
            myLabelGenerated1stDigit.BackColor= Color.LightGray;
            myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

            //for any generated digit that matches the winning digit,
            if (random1 == userEntered1stDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated1stDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
            if (random2 == userEntered2ndDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
            if (random3 == userEntered3rdDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }

            //  -keep track of the matching status of each digit in a boolean

            bool theyMatch = (random1 == userEntered1stDigit) && (random2 == userEntered2ndDigit) && (random3 == userEntered3rdDigit);

            //check all three boolean match variables, if they are all true then we have a match to the winning number, exit out of the while
            if (theyMatch)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success! Match found for all 3 digits. It took " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //add what happened to the event log
                MessageBox.Show("No match found after " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
                return;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are return'ing without checking if the loops have been consumed
Remove the else and put it outside while, and also change break to return

```
//...

    if (theyMatch)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success! Match found for all 3 digits. It took " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
        return;
    }

}

MessageBox.Show("No match found after " + myAttemptsInt + " tries.");
```

Comment: I changed break to return, but I'm having a hard time moving things. he wants this last statement to end the "while" loop. So I need to say "if we have a match, end the loop" "if we dont have a match, keep going" Re-reading the instructions, BOTH messagebox.shows come after the loop, so what the heck goes IN it to end it?

Comment: these are his exact instructions: if (??)
                {
                    //add what happened to the event log

                    //break out of while loop since found a match
                    break;
                    //
                }
                else
                {
                    //add what happened to the event log

                    //no need to break out of loop; keep looping
                }

Comment: Nope, the loop will end because you already put "while (myAttemptsInt <= 1000)", so you don't need to explicitly end the loop unless it's before the counter reaches 1000, in that case the return inside the loop will completely exit the function and the second messagebox will not be displayed.

Comment: Ok, see your new comment, if you want to do this way, the second return must be totally removed and a messagebox will be shown on each loop. With a messagebox it's a pain, but if you log to a file/textbox it makes sense, you will have X rows with "No match for this iteration", and one with "match found" or "match not found after 1000 iterations"

Comment: I see now, I moved that whole chunk to after the loop and it works. If he meant for it to be inside, it doesn't make a lot of sense lol. Thanks again!